# Cannot parse JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

Here's my javascript file

```
var callAjax = function(relative_path){
        var Ajax =  new XMLHttpRequest();
            Ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

                //Since what we are calling a local file. we cannot get a 200 OK Status.
                //So We check only the readystate
                if(Ajax.readyState==4){
                    serialized = Ajax.responseText;
                    alert(serialized); 
                    // ^^ alerts fine.
                    return serialized;
                }

            }

            Ajax.open("GET",relative_path, true);
            Ajax.send();    
};


var readSettings = function(){
    var data = callAjax('settings.json');
    obj  = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj);
}
```

Now when i call `readSettings()` somewhere in my html, the first alert (in the callAjax functions alerts the JSON correctly. but the second one does not. When i see the console, the error is :

> [21:04:02.233] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character @ file:///home/cipher/Codes/looma-f5/js/looma.js:23

My settings.json is:

```
{

    "classes": 8,
    "config": "classConfig",
    "locale": {
        "en": "localeEn"
    },
    "defaultLocale": "en"
}
```

I ran the JSON through online tools, it looks good. Why is  firefox not parsing these?

Comment: Is your json in utf-8?

Comment: I see that was not the real cause of error :). Anyways, thanks @Sumurai8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning any value from the `callAjax` function. You need to put your code that uses the result inside the `onreadystatchange` handler.

You *do* have a `return` statement, but it's inside the callback, which returns to the internal caller of the callback, and which is invoked after your `callAjax` returned.

Since it seems that `callAjax` is fairly generic, a good approach is to have that function accept a callback as an argument, then invoke it, passing in the response.

```
//                  receive a callback----vv
var callAjax = function(relative_path, callback){
        var Ajax =  new XMLHttpRequest();

        Ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(Ajax.readyState==4){
                serialized = Ajax.responseText;
                alert(serialized); 

                // vv---invoke the callback
                callback(serialized);
            }
        }
        Ajax.open("GET",relative_path, true);
        Ajax.send(); 
};

var readSettings = function(){
    // pass a callback ----------------------vv
    var data = callAjax('settings.json', function(data) {
        var obj  = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj);
    });
}
```

---

If the caller of `readSettings` needs to work with the response, then you could have `readSettings` also receive a callback, and then either pass it on directly, or wrap it in another function so that it can first do the parsing.

I'll give an example that assumes that it needs to be wrapped.

```
// receive a callback----------vv
var readSettings = function(callback){
    // pass a callback that wraps the first---vv
    var data = callAjax('settings.json', function(data) {
        // parse the response data
        var obj  = JSON.parse(data);

        // invoke the callback, passing it the parsed object
        callback(obj);
    });
}
```

---

```
readSettings(function(settings_obj) {
    alert(settings_obj);
});
```

Comment: While putting the code in a callback handler is a good start I wouldn't recommend nesting all future code in there ;) (just a side note).

Comment: Damn! My silly mistake. I tried using a callback (as a matter of fact: had used the same vars :)), but the problem was i could not return `obj` via readSettings? Any way to workaround! @MichaelKrelin-hacker @BlueSkies

Comment: @cipher: Yeah, it's the same problem. Whatever invokes `readSettings` could pass in a callback, which could be passed on to `callAjax`. If needed, it could be passed on inside another function which does the parsing first. I'll update with an example.

Comment: @cipher, I think you need to change your flows, just get accustomed to asynchronous delivery or more or less any results.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @MichaelKrelin-hacker , @ BlueSkies. I acutally wanted to keep the settings object in a global scope so that i could access it later. But it seems that even if i assign the value of parsed object to a global variable, there is a chance that the variable may not set when i am accessing it.

Thank you again. :)

Comment: Yes, you also need to make sure that all of your further proceedings happen after populating the object. Just trigger them from this same callback.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can `JSON.parse` immediately after `callAjax` returns. Before the `onreadystate` callback is executed. Due to asynchronous nature of the operation you should trigger parsing from the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The "A" in AJAX is for asynchronous. After submitting the XMLHttpRequest, the `callAjax` function will return immediately, without waiting for the request to complete. Thus, the `JSON.parse` will be called with the return value of `callAjax` (which isn't the JSON you're looking for), generating the error.

Some time later, the XMLHttpRequest will complete and the `onreadystatechange` callback will be run. You return the JSON from this function, but the JSON doesn't go anywhere because it's returning from the callback, not from `callAjax`.

You must perform the JSON parsing and subsequent activities as a result of the `onreadystatechange` event.